# How to bind an combobox to an extended class with type?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I haven an combobox in wpf and would like to bind it to an attribute of an object. My problem is, that this attribute is an base class an can be two concrete types.

These are my classes:

```
    public abstract class Database
    {
        public DBTypes Type { get; set; }
        public abstract void connect();

        public abstract void disconnect();

        public abstract void initDB();


        public Database()
        {

        }
    }

 public class OracleDB : Database
    {
        public string Sid { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        private OracleConnection m_dbConnection;

        public OracleDB()
        {
            Type = DBTypes.ORACLE;
        }

        public OracleDB( string sid, string user, string passwd )
        {
            Sid = sid;
            User = user;
            Password = passwd;
        }
        .
        . 
        .
}

    public class SqliteDB : Database
    {
        public string DBFile { get; set; }

        private SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;

        public SqliteDB()
        {
            DBFile = "database.db";
            Type = DBTypes.SQLITE;
        }

        .
        .
     }
}

 public enum DBTypes
    {
        ORACLE,
        SQLITE
    }
```

WPF part is:

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}" x:Key="EnumValues">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="lib:DBTypes" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>

.
.
.

<ComboBox x:Name="DBTyp"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumValues}}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DbSettings.Type}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DbSettings}">
            </ComboBox>
```

DbSettings is the attribute of type Database.

So how can i achieve that when selecting another entry from the combobox, the correct object is selected?

With my Code im getting

```
Cannot convert 'SQLITE' from type 'DBTypes' to type 'Database' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter kann nicht von DBTypes konvertieren.
```

Comment: What is the type of DbSettings. If it's type is Database, You should remove SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DbSettings}". That is causing the error. If I understood correctly you are trying to set Type property on DbSettings.

Comment: Yes the type of DbSettings is Database. I have read your answer too late, but it goese in the same direction as @mm8 mentioned. Therre canont be SelectedItem and SelectedValue at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `SelectedItem` property to `DbSettings.Type`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DBTyp" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumValues}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DbSettings.Type}">
</ComboBox>
```

You should not bind both `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem`.